# Filtering for date based on year

Tags: sql, presto

What would be the best way if I want to filter query if the year in date column is > let's say 2014 and another scenario if it is between years of 2016 and 2019?

Can you properly use something like below

```
where date_trunc('year',date_column) > '2014'     
where date_trunc('year', date_column) between '2016' and 2019'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine these conditions into one like below

```
where date_trunc('year', date_column) between '2016' and 2019'
```

Because of > 2014 means in range 2016 & 2019.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Chris90

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use those methods.  But functions on columns generally impede the optimizer.  So I would recommend:

```
where date_column >= '2014-01-01' and
      date_column < '2015-01-01'
```

and:

```
where date_column >= '2016-01-01' and
      date_column < '2020-01-01'
```